# SonarQube Scanner: are binaries really needed?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm running SonarQube scanner on a java project. In the properties file there's a property `sonar.java.binaries=**/classes` to specify classes location for the projects.

The scan failed showing this error:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property
```

when:

1. I removed the `sonar.java.binaries` property
2. I set `sonar.java.binaries` property to `null`
3. I set the property to `sonar.java.binaries=**/classes` but in the project directories there was no classes dir or there were empty ones

The scan was completed successfully when:

1. I set the property `sonar.java.binaries=**/classes` and I created a classes folder putting into it a bogus file `blabla.class`

So my question is: why are the classes required if the scanner is working also without them?

Comment: If sonar is determining the code coverage by running the unit tests, it requires the compiled classes against which to run the unit tests.

Comment: You mean Sonar needs the classes only for the unit test coverage?

Comment: What reason do you have not providing the classes?

Comment: I mean what I said.  If Sonar is determining the code coverage, then it needs the compiled classes.  It may use the compiled classes for something else as well.  I don't know all the reasons why Sonar wants the compiled classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied from the [official documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJava):

> **Java bytecode is required**
>
> Analyzing a Java project without providing the Java bytecode produced by `javac` (Android users: Jack doesn't provide the required `.class` files) and all project dependencies (jar files) is possible, but will result in an increased number of false negatives, i.e. legitimate issues will be missed by the analyzer.
>
> From SonarJava version 4.12 binary files are required for java projects with more than one java file. If not provided properly, analysis will fail with the message
>
> `Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property`
>
> See [Java Plugin and Bytecode](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin+and+Bytecode) for how to provide the Java bytecode if you are not using Maven to run your analysis.

As you see, the bytecode is required. If you don't feed the analyzer with the bytecode then built syntax/dependecy tree will miss some data, and you get more false negatives (issues which should be reported, but weren't).